# Conceptial questions: AP Computer Science

Tags: methods, types

Can someone explain the following questions: 
What is the type of an object?

Why can't a method be called on any object in any class?

Why can't a method have multiple implicit parameters?

Is there any difference between algorithm and pseudocode?

Comment: The correct answer is "class"? I'm not so sure about that..

Comment: Really? Then my teacher's wrong?